# Is transaction.set(...) synchronous?

Tags: angular, firebase, promise, transactions, async-await

I’m working with a database transaction in my angular/firebase project. I have this:

```
const transactionResult = await db.runTransaction(async trans => {
            // Get references:
            const parentGroupRef = db.collection('Groups').doc(parentGroupID);
            const childGroupRef = db.collection('Groups').doc(childGroupID);

            // Get documents:
            const promiseArray: Promise<any>[] = [];
            promiseArray.push(trans.get(parentGroupRef));
            promiseArray.push(trans.get(childGroupRef));
            const promiseResults: any[] = await Promise.all(promiseArray);

            // Get the group documents of the promise results:
            const parentGroupDoc = promiseResults.filter(groupDoc => { return groupDoc.id === parentGroupID; })[0];
            const childGroupDoc = promiseResults.filter(groupDoc => { return groupDoc.id === childGroupID; })[0];

            // Get data:
            if (parentGroupDoc && parentGroupDoc.exists && childGroupDoc && childGroupDoc.exists) {
                const parentGroupData = parentGroupDoc.data();
                const childGroupData = childGroupDoc.data();

                // Add child to parent and visa-versa:
                const results: any[] = [];
                if (parentGroupData.childGroupIDs.indexOf(childGroupID) === -1) {
                    parentGroupData.childGroupIDs.push(childGroupID);   
                    const addChildResult = trans.set(parentGroupRef, parentGroupData, {merge: true});
                    results.push(addChildResult);
                }

                if (childGroupData.parentGroupIDs.indexOf(parentGroupID) === -1) {
                    childGroupData.parentGroupIDs.push(parentGroupID);
                    const addParentResult = trans.set(childGroupRef, childGroupData, {merge: true});
                    results.push(addParentResult);
                }

                if (results.length > 0) {
                    return await Promise.all(results);
                } else {
                    return Promise.reject('No changes made');
                }
            } else {
                console.log('Could not find parent or child group, or both.');
                return Promise.reject('Could not find parent or child group, or both.');
            }
        });
```

As you can see, I’m awaiting the promises returned from trans.get(…). Does it make sense to do the same for trans.set(…)? It makes sense to do it for trans.get(…) because trans.get(…) returns a promise. But trans.set(…) returns a transaction object. So my question is: is trans.set(…) synchronous?

Comment: What's your question? Since you answered it yourself: if it doesn't return ` Promise`, it's synchronous by definition.

Answer (score 0):

All Firebase APIs that interact with the remote service are asynchronous, including the API for transactions.

Read: [Why are Firebase APIs Asynchronous?](https://medium.com/google-developers/why-are-firebase-apis-asynchronous-callbacks-promises-tasks-e037a6654a93)